# Can someone explain this maven-jar-plugin configuration?

Tags: java, maven

I'm still new to maven, so to familiarize myself with how it works I've been looking through working samples around the internet. I came across this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>${startupClass}</mainClass>
                <classpathPrefix>${app.lib.dir}</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

From what I can tell, it looks as if this actualy grabs external references and includes them in the final JAR, which doesn't make sense because I thought the whole point of using maven was to have maven work out dependencies for you?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin is configured to create a classpath entry in the manifest file of a jar. In addition it will create a MainClass entry, with the startupClass property's value. Also, it will prefix each maven dependency it adds to the classpath entry with the value stored in the app.lib.dir property.

I have used these in the past in combination with the maven-dependency-plugin. I use that plugin to copy all of the maven jars to a lib folder, then I use the plugin you have there, in the same way as you to set up the classpath and main class entries in my manifest file.

Although I would like to point out that without the < version/ > node, that plugin will not add the classPath entry to the manifest file. At lest it wont with my version of eclipse/maven. I would advise adding < version >2.4< /version > to the plugins definition.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/